# Smooth scrolling with Router Scroller

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using Router Scroller to scroll  but it jumps to the  element instead of scrolling. Is there a way to make it more smooth or slower? Also if I scroll up or down and then click again on the anchor it doesn't scroll back to that element. It only works once .

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    })
],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: are you importing `AppRoutingModule ` in your main module?

Comment: yes i did, if you add this  it will solve  the problem if you click again on the link and it will jump to section (   onSameUrlNavigation: "reload" ), but the smooth scrolling i still didnt find out how to solve it

Comment: you can find explanation here
 https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3537-polyfilling-the-second-click-of-a-routerlink-fragment-in-angular-7-1-1.htm